# Unselecting input value in a showInputBox for visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When displaying an input box via showInputBox with a default value, visual studio code displays input box with default value selected. Is there a way to unselect the default value and put the cursor at the end of the string?

Is there an event fired before the input box is shown, where I can unselect the default value?

Thank you

Comment: Any updates on this issue? Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a placeholder, but the thing you're asking for is not possible.

As a workaround, you could provide a default value like "-" that would be first on the list. Selecting it could abort or repeat the command.

Comment: Our extension shows file paths for some default values. User have an option to modify the file path or accept the default value. Therefore, showing "-" as a default value is not an option in our case. With the default value selected issue is if user starts typing in the input box it takes away the default value. There are times where user just want to modify a portion of the file path.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but in case it helps someone.  A `valueSelection` property has been added to `InputBox`.

To put the cursor at the end of your default `value` string, use a tuple with the start = end or in the case of `Howdy there` 11.

To get it to work in a javascript extension I had to include the type declaration `/** @type { [number, number] } */` otherwise I got an error complaining that

```
Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type '[number, number]'."
```

```js
/** @type { [number, number] } */
let vs = [11, 11];                     // length of your default value string
const options = {value: "Howdy there", valueSelection: vs};
const inputBox = await vscode.window.showInputBox(options);
```

In a typescript extension you can use this:

```
let vs: [number, number] = [11, 11];
const options = {value: "Howdy there", valueSelection: vs};
const inputBox = await vscode.window.showInputBox(options);
```